# Return Void from function LLVM

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir, llvm-gcc

I have created a function in LLVM IR. Now I want to create  a return instruction `return void`.

I saw the function Create `ReturnInst::(LLVMContext &C, Value *retVal, BasicBlock *InsertAtEnd)`

But I don't know what should `retVal` should be so that it returns `return void`

Answer (score 8):

If you pass in nullptr to retVal (which is its default value too) that will give you a 'ret void'.

Answer (score 1):

Seems this code works:
`UndefValue::get(Type::getVoidTy(Context))`